# Jmeter - Client side verification

Tags: jmeter

I am working on a web application, which accepts Email alert by entering mail id. Once its submitted, it shows email id with confirmation message. I put an assertion on the response to verify the mail id is shown correctly. But it failed due to server response. Server response does not have mail id. It has success or fail response only. But sometimes mail id is not shown correctly in the page. We need to prove it. Below is the response...

{
:   "d":"{\"ResponseObjectContainer\":null,\"Response\":null,\"ErrorMessage\":null,\"Status\":\"SUCCESS\",\"ValidationErrors\":null}"
}

Based on the server response, a javascript function is triggered to show the success or error message on the web page with mail id.

Please tell me, Does Jmeter have any component or method to verify the client side html code validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [JMeter project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser
>
> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So JMeter won't execute the JavaScript automatically. If the JavaScript triggers i.e. an [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) request checking the status you could replicate it by adding another [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which will execute the same request and add a [JSON Path Assertion](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) to check the status. You can install JSON Path Assertion using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter JSON Plugins]

Comment: Thank you for your valuable inputs. Is it possible to run Jmeter Selenium Webdriver config after the response and validate the content?